# Animating an html element in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

"monitor" is a box which shows enlarged text everytime mouse is hovered on a part of the page(web)

"+" and "-" are the two buttons which help me increase and decrease the box size,respectively.

The problem arises when text in the box overflows the box and makes my code look inefficient. Here is a sample for making the plus button increase box size(text size)
In simple words I just want to put some limit on this box so that its size gets a threshold value and a maximum value

```
$('div.monitor').animate({ 'fontSize': '+=10pt' }, 'fast'); return false; break;
```

Comment: I don't get it... Why can't you do it by decreasing the addition number in the .animate method? And what do you mean by threshold value?

Comment: Just to put some minimum and maximum on the box size so that it cannot grow beyond those limits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like the logic of the other answer given by @Raminson. It says "if size of the font is less than 40px then increase the size by 10". Then the size limit (the box container) could be a maximum of 49px (if initial condition is =39px). I would do something like this:

```
while ($('div.monitor').css('font-size') != "40px") {
    $('div.monitor').animate({ 'fontSize': '+=1px' }, 'fast');
}
```

this way, it increases 1 at the time and gets to the desired value = 40px.

You could even do:

```
while ($('div.monitor').css('font-size') != "40px") {
    $('div.monitor').css( 'fontSize', '+=1px');
}
```

and it would look like an animation

Comment: I am using a switch statement where 
if some presses a..> b
c...>d
using a switch statement So i am unable to use if or while etc

Comment: What does it mean? in what way using a switch statement doesn't allow you to use a while loop inside it?

Comment: I am using this like

$('html').keydown(function (event) {

        var requestedAction = null;



        switch (event.keyCode) {

  /* + */ case 107: while ($('div.monitor').css('font-size') != "40px") {
                    $('div.monitor').css('fontSize', '+=5px');
                } return false; break;
Am I doing it correct?